# Expanding Debian system partition

Tags: partition, storage

I have a VM (with little space) running `Debian 9` and a drive of 100 GB. I want to configure it as a LAMP web server.
I followed a tutorial to mount that drive on `/data`, this is my partition table:

```
$ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0              2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda              8:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─sda1           8:1    0  243M  0 part /boot
└─sda2           8:2    0 19,8G  0 part
  ├─vgsys-root 254:0    0  9,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vgsys-var  254:1    0  1,9G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─vgsys-usr  254:2    0  3,8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─vgsys-home 254:3    0  1,9G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─vgsys-tmp  254:4    0  1,9G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─vgsys-swap 254:5    0  732M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb              8:16   0  100G  0 disk
└─sdb1           8:17   0  100G  0 part /data
sr0             11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I'm not sure whether I can redirect my future installations to this partition or I'll just continue filling up my system partition. If so, can I use this 100 GB to expand file partitions instead of having it as a separate folder?
How does disk partition work?

Comment: As you are already using logical volumes, you may want to add the additional disk to your lvm-pool.  Then you can grow/shrink individual volumes as needed.

Comment: What do you want to have on `/data`? Software installations using normal software packages will most probably ignore `/data`. Depending on which virtual machine software you are using, you might be able to increase the size of your virtual harddisk or copy it to a bigger virtual harddisk and then move and resize the partitions using `gparted` from a live system.

Comment: Disk partitioning is not linux-specific, windows also partitions its disks. However, in your situation, I would not use a separate /data partition, but add the new disk to the LVM volume group you already have (`vgsys`), and then resize the device on which `/var` resides; after increasing the size of the device, you can resize the filesystem on that device. https://linuxtechlab.com/beginners-guide-resizing-lvm/ has some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies

@wurtel : Thanks for the link, it works perfectly now

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0              2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda              8:0    0    20G  0 disk
├─sda1           8:1    0   243M  0 part /boot
└─sda2           8:2    0  19,8G  0 part
  ├─vgsys-root 254:0    0 109,5G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vgsys-var  254:1    0   1,9G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─vgsys-usr  254:2    0   3,8G  0 lvm  /usr
  ├─vgsys-home 254:3    0   1,9G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─vgsys-tmp  254:4    0   1,9G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─vgsys-swap 254:5    0   732M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb              8:16   0   100G  0 disk
└─sdb1           8:17   0   100G  0 part
  └─vgsys-root 254:0    0 109,5G  0 lvm  /
sr0             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```